Express a set as a union of two disjoint sets
Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $S$.
a) Express $A$ as a union of two disjoint sets.
b) Express $A \cup B$ as a union of three mutually exclusive sets.

I suggest you see this article How do I ask a good question

What is $S$? A subset of $\mathbb R$ or something else?

$A=A\cup\emptyset$ is as you require.
